# Outsourcing implementation of a function contains $http, $scope and other parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, code-reuse

I'm trying to reuse my code, but I don't know, how to do it exactly.

I have a dropdownlist, which contains all the users. If I click on a user, the

```
$scope.UserHasBeenSelected = function (username) {
```

runs. It's fine. But I want to get the same output if the user clicks a link on a different page, and it redirects the user to this one, but having the selected user's name as parameter. To be able to do it, I had to duplicate the code... Which is basically a bad approach.

I have a Controller for my template html, which looks like this:

```
var MonthlySummaryController = function ($scope, $http, $stateParams) {

//FILL IN the drop-downList
$http.get('DataProviderService.asmx/GetUsersAndTheirState')
.then(function (response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
});

//COPY-PASTE From HERE
if ($stateParams.userName) {
  //Do something with the username
  ...
}
//COPY-PASTE To HERE
...

// if a user has been picked: (This is the method which can be called outside the HTML)
$scope.UserHasBeenSelected = function (username) {
  //Do THE SAME with the username as before. (This is the inner code which is duplicated)
  ...
}

angular.module("Home").controller("monthlySummaryController", MonthlySummaryController);
```

As can be seen, I have a function containing the code, and had to duplicate it to do the same if there are parameters given.

Do you have any idea how to outsource it as a function, and call it from the Controller itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you need is to move your duplicate code to a `service`. You could create a service like this:

```
yourApp.service('yourServiceName', function() {
    return {
        yourDuplicateMethod: function (userName) {
            // Do all the stuff with the username here...
        }
    }
});
```

And then use inject it and use it in your controller:

```
var MonthlySummaryController = function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, yourServiceName) {

//FILL IN the drop-downList
$http.get('DataProviderService.asmx/GetUsersAndTheirState')
.then(function (response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
});

//COPY-PASTE From HERE
if ($stateParams.userName) {
  yourServiceName.yourDuplicateMethod($stateParams.userName);
}
//COPY-PASTE To HERE
...

// if a user has been picked: (This is the method which can be called outside the HTML)
$scope.UserHasBeenSelected = function (username) {
  yourServiceName.yourDuplicateMethod(userName);
}

angular.module("Home").controller("monthlySummaryController", MonthlySummaryController);
```

Comment: But how could I use $scope in "yourDuplicateMethod"? Because I have to use scope and http services in my code.

Comment: You can inject $http service in your custom 'yourServiceName' service and use it the same way you do in your controller. About the use of scope... I think you could pass it as a parameter to 'yourDuplicateMethod' but I'm not sure if it is a good design idea. If you provide some more detail of your duplicate code maybe we can help you refactor it in order to make it more modular. You can edit your question and/or provide us with a plunker with a working example of your code. Kind regards.

Comment: I injected the http and scope service into my own service (yourServiceName) Now, I can use it as a "real" function. Which is nice. I have some questions right now, but after I eliminate each of my problems, I'll had back to here to see whether this answer was accomplished.

Comment: I could manage to solve all of my problems, so I could accept your answer as right. Thank you for your help and time :) I've learned a new thing.

Comment: I'm glad It helped and I'm glad I could teach someone a new thing :). Kind regards.